# How do I convert ejs to handlebars?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, ejs, partials, parse-error

I am trying to convert this ejs code to handlebars. I am taking a tutorial so it's giving me a bit of problems. I would be glad to get any help

```
<% if(typeof errors!= 'undefined') { %>
<%    errors.forEach(function(error){ %>
<p> <%= error.msg %></p>
<%    })        %>
<% } %>
```

This is my conversion:

```
{{#if typeof errors !== "undefined"}}
  {{#each error}}
    <p>{{error.msg}}</p>
  {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
{{#if typeof errors !== "undefined"}}  
--------------------^
Expecting 'CLOSE_RAW_BLOCK', 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'OPEN_SEXPR', 'CLOSE_SEXPR', 'ID', 'EQUALS', 'OPEN_BLOCK_PARAMS', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', 'SEP', got 'INVALID'
    at Parser.parseError (/home/bunny/Tales/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/parser.js:267:19)
    at Parser.parse (/home/bunny/Tales/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/parser.js:336:30)
    at parseWithoutProcessing (/home/bunny/Tales/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/base.js:46:33)
    at HandlebarsEnvironment.parse (/home/bunny/Tales/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/base.js:52:13)
    at compileInput (/home/bunny/Tales/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/compiler.js:508:19)
    at ret (/home/bunny/Tales/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/compiler.js:517:18)
    at Object.invokePartial (/home/bunny/Tales/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:334:12)
    at Object.invokePartialWrapper [as invokePartial] (/home/bunny/Tales/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:84:39)
    at Object.eval [as main] (eval at createFunctionContext (/home/bunny/Tales/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/javascript-compiler.js:262:23), <anonymous>:10:31)
    at main (/home/bunny/Tales/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:208:32)
    at ret (/home/bunny/Tales/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:212:12)
    at ret (/home/bunny/Tales/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/compiler.js:519:21)
    at ExpressHandlebars._renderTemplate (/home/bunny/Tales/node_modules/express-handlebars/lib/express-handlebars.js:250:9)
    at ExpressHandlebars.<anonymous> (/home/bunny/Tales/node_modules/express-handlebars/lib/express-handlebars.js:173:15)
```

Also, I want to add this ejs partial file to my handlebars and this is what I did. I don't know how correct I am:

```
Ejs:
<%- include ('./partials/messages') %>

Handlebars:
{{> _messages}}
```

Comment: Hello, please add your handlebars version with `npm view [package] version`

Comment: The handle bar version is 4.7.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handlebars syntax doesn't look right, your conversion should be:

```
{{#if errors }}
  {{#each errors}}
    <p>{{ this.msg }}</p>
  {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

`{{#if errors }}` checks if `error` is `undefined` or `[]` (https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#if)

Also, `this` is used to reference the element being iterated over (https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#each).